# zend lucene how set priority on keyword field

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, indexing

It possible to set permanent bonus of revelance for some keyword field?
I have product name field, id keyword field and priority keyword field. I want to set revelance of results like revelance of search+priority of result.

```
 //id of product
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('pk', $this->getId(), "utf-8"));

  //i want set permanent revelance bonus on that field
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('priotity', "priority", "utf-8"));

  //field for search
  $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('description', $this->getDescription(), "utf-8"));
```

For example i search for apple iphone and
results must be like:
maximum coincidence max priority,
maximum coincidence next priority,
maximum coincidence next priority

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to set permanent bonus to a field in the context of scoring.

Here is the [Tutorial](http://davedash.com/2007/05/29/boosting-terms-in-zend-search-lucene/)

I'm not sure with this zend Lucene, but the method [Field.setBoost()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#setBoost%28float%29) is how we do in plain Lucene. I'm sure there must be an equivalent way of doing it with zend Lucene because that's a basic feature.

The following is the snippet from the above tutorial.

```
    $field = Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('firstname', $this->getFirstname());
    $field->boost = 1.5;
```

I cannot guarantee the above snippet's validity, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: What i need to do if i only store that field, but don't search with that field? And second question-how i can get revelance of every elements, what i get from find?

Comment: I do
$boostField=Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('priority',$word['priority']);
            $boostField->boost=1.5;
            $doc->addField($boostField);

but it don't work. I don't use in search that field. That field just store and gave boost bonus to search results

Comment: what do you mean by 'it didn't work'?. Please elaborate your requirements.

Comment: I only store information about priority. I don't use that information when i search. In field "priority" i have only numbers-how on result better of another results.